Create "playing by ear" tag?
As Tim noted in a recent question, there isn't a tag about "playing by ear." We do have improvisation (and jamming, see my Meta Q about the overlap) and ear-training. But to define our terms, this would specifically be about learning new musical material by listening rather than via notation, whereas improvisation is about ex tempore musical creation, and ear-training is a training practice as an end in itself.
Searching the site for the string "by ear" and limiting to questions yields 286 results; adding in answers brings it to 1,118. Some of these are false positives, like talk about "tuning by ear," but it still seems like there's plenty of talk on the topic.

How is learning by ear different from ear training? That is, are there questions about learning by ear that don't amount to "how do I train my ear to do this?"

@Aaron I'd say different in practice and culture. The answer to that question is usually "do some ear training," but the ear training itself is an end to a separate goal. And, that's the answer given mostly by trained musicians; ear training is a conservatory course, and comes out of a formal culture. Within traditions dominated by self-learning and by playing-by-ear, the learning doesn't usually use a curriculum or textbook, and although it might go acquire similar skills in similar (unconscious) ways, it's not referred to as "ear training."

@Aaron Besides Tim's question, https://music.stackexchange.com/q/108461/78419 might be an example of one that isn't about ear-training courses (even if it might be the answer that the OP is unaware of). There are also countless "how do I get better" questions that have been tagged with "ear-training" even though nothing in the question mentions or even overtly implies an interest in a formalized course involving solfege etc., just a desire to be able to acquire melody aurally.

But what about the ear training tag restricts it to formalized training? I’ve trained people without solfège, for example. Are you suggesting adding a restriction to the existing tag and then retagging everything with the new one? My experience here suggests 1) there are relatively few questions about formalized training, and 2) the change would actually make searches by tag harder, because the answer to an “informal” question could be formal and vice-versa.

@Aaron Hm, good point; the vast majority of questions about "playing by ear" are about how to improve, and ergo about training. Not all, though; Tim's recent one and the one I linked are asking about "people who play by ear" and their practices. (Both admittedly have their issues of being broad.)

By "Tim's question", do you mean the one about learning by notation versus learning by ear? Honestly, I think that question should have been closed and voted to do so. At least, I don't think it's a good example of the distinction you're looking to make in the larger sense, because it's an uneasy fit for the site (IMO).

@Aaron Looks like this meta question put a spotlight in "learning by listening" though I think the proposed tag is about a broader "playing by ear". Personally, I feel "ear training" is not the same as "playing by ear". At the very least, I don't feel I'm doing an ear training when I try to transcribe a random song by listening to it (granted, there's already [tag:transcription] tag). I might be training my ear at the same time, but that's not my main purpose. Or perhaps my definition of this tag is misleading...

@AndrewT It's not so much that ear training and playing by ear are the same thing; it's that the questions on both topic come down to matters of ear training.

@AndrewT. I think, since Aaron brought it up, there are very few questions about “playing by ear” that are not “how do I get better at it,“ to which a frequent answer is “ear training.“ I think what I need to do is look through those search results and see how many fall outside of that.

This sounds to me like a good call. Seems like the numbers are there to justify it. Let's leave the question open for a few days to see if there is any vehement dissent, but if not, we'll add it.
Then we just need to go and tag em all... (but not all at once!)

I think the tag is unnecessary and has the potential to create confusion. Andy and I have a discussion about this in the comments on his OP.
